# Passing props using less text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, react-props

I've recently started using Styled Components, I can see what the fuss is about but there are some things that I'm either not understanding properly or are just not DRY at all. Take this example where I create a Card component, and I'm using the Material UI scheme at the same time:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/macro'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const S_Card = styled(Grid)`
    background-color: rgb(191, 161, 228);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: ${props => props.height};
    margin: ${props => props.marg}; 
    margin-left: ${props => props.margleft};
    margin-right: ${props => props.margright};
    margin-top: ${props => props.margtop};
    margin-bottom: ${props => props.margbottom};
    padding: ${props => props.pad}; 
    padding-left: ${props => props.padleft};
    padding-right: ${props => props.padright};
    padding-top: ${props => props.padtop};
    padding-bottom: ${props => props.padbottom};
`

export default function Card(props) {
const p = props

return(

    <S_Card 
        container
        item
        xs = {p.xs} 
        md = {p.md}
        alignItems = {p.alignItems}
        justify = {p.justify}
        height = {p.height}
        pad = {p.pad}
        padleft = {p.padleft}
        padright = {p.padright}
        padtop = {p.padtop}
        padbottom = {p.padbottom}
        marg = {p.marg}
        margleft = {p.margleft}
        margright = {p.margright}
        margtop = {p.margtop}
        margbottom = {p.margbottom}
    >
        {p.children}
    </S_Card>

    )
}
```

Let's say in this case I'm going to call this component from somewhere else typing this:

```
<Card xs = {4} height = '100px' padleft = '10px' padright = '10px' margtop = '20px' margbottom = '20px />'
```

I think the problem is pretty obvious here. Way too many lines just to set up something as simple as paddings and margins.

Do I have to declare all these props in order to pass them through to the style wrapper *const S_Card = styled(Grid)`* ?

It seems like such a big amount of lines to be repeated for a lot of components (most components are going to have to pass through margins, paddings, etc, which means a lot of lines). So I assume I'm not doing this the right way, how do I improve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spread syntax (...) to  clean up the code instead of deconstructing each prop individually:

```
export default function Card(props) {

return(

    <S_Card 
        container
        item
        {...props}
    />

    )
}
```

The spread notation will also take care of rendering the `children`, so  I was comfortable removing it as well.

Comment: Thanks Shimi! That solves half the problem already, very helpful! That leaves me only with the lines inside the Styled wrapper, and as it happens I have a solution for that, pls see my answer where I try to put together your solution with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shimi, who provided a very quick and elegant solution to half of my problem by removing the lines defining the props for the component and using a spread.
As it happens, I can contribute further here and get rid of maybe another 25% of lines. The solution would be:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/macro'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const S_Card = styled(Grid)`
    background-color: rgb(191, 161, 228);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ${props => props.mixins.widthHeight}
    ${props => props.mixins.margins}
    ${props => props.mixins.paddings}
`

export default function Card(props) {

return(

    <S_Card 
        container
        item
        {...props}
    />

    )
}
```

What I did here is I have a separate file where I write mixins (or what would be the equivalent of SASS mixins in Styled Components). A mixin would look like this:

```
import {css} from 'styled-components'

const paddings = css`
    padding: ${props => props.pad}; 
    padding-left: ${props => props.padleft};
    padding-right: ${props => props.padright};
    padding-top: ${props => props.padtop};
    padding-bottom: ${props => props.padbottom};
`
```

I'm pretty satisfied with this solution as it does away with a lot of lines. Thanks again Shimi. Would actually be pretty awesome if someone could get rid of even more lines here :D

Comment: Looking much cleaner!
I would also remove `const p = props` and just change the spread notation to `{...props}` instead of `{...p}`.

Comment: Of course! Was doing const p = props so that if I suddenly want to use p = props.whatever I don't have to change a lot of lines, but of course you're right and that line can go now, editing :d

Comment: And to clean  that even  further, you can replace:
```
    >
        {p.children}
    </S_Card>
```

with
```
/>
```
The spread notation will take care of the children as well, and it  is less code :)

Comment: I'll edit my answer to accommodate that, so it will be  clearer.

Comment: I realized that since most components are going to receive the same props (margins, paddings, width, height, etc) we could reduce even a little bit more by having one general mixin that includes width, height, all margins, all paddings, etc. and it would occupy only one line in the styled component section. I won't edit so that each can see how it's done in the example, but we could reduce lines further that way here :D

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I like the granularity of flexibility you provided in your solution, but I agree that there could be more ways to optimize it if needed  -  depends on the usecases.